# How to use onclick method inside AEM component

Tags: aem

Am having a AEM6 html component, am getting the values from dialog and using it inside the component via the .js file and using the return properties.

I could able to get the authored values but it is getting null or empty when am using it inside the onclick method. Please find below the code snippet below.

```
<div data-sly-unwrap data-sly-use.test="test.js"></div>

<a href="#" class="${test.testId}" id="${test.testId}" onClick="toggleDraw('${test.testId}')" >
```

The content I authored is getting displayed in class and Id, but it is not displaying in the  onClick method.

Below is the Output am getting after authoring.

```
<a href="#" class="get-a-quote" id="get-a-quote" onClick="toggleDraw('')" >
```

Output I needed is :

```
<a href="#" class="get-a-quote" id="get-a-quote" onClick="toggleDraw('get-a-quote')" >
```

Comment: Your output is missing.

Comment: <div data-sly-unwrap data-sly-use.test="test.js"></div>

<a href="#" class="${test.testId}" id="${test.testId}" onClick="toggleDraw('${test.testId}')" >

 

The content I authored is getting displayed in class and Id, but it is not displaying in the  onClick method.

 

 

Below is the Output am getting after authoring.

<a href="#" class="get-a-quote" id="get-a-quote" onClick="toggleDraw('')" >

 

Output I needed is :

<a href="#" class="get-a-quote" id="get-a-quote" onClick="toggleDraw('get-a-quote')" >

Comment: No, please edit your question and paste the code in the original question text, thanks.

Comment: can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<a data-sly-test.variable123="toggleDraw('${test.testId}')" href="#" class="${test.testId}" id="${test.testId}" onclick="${variable123 @ context='attribute'}" >
```

You need to put the function call in a variable because of the nested single quotes. And you need to manually set the context in this case. If "attribute" does some escaping you do not like, you could use "unsafe" - this will end in all escaping mechanisms being disabled. That might or might not be a security issue for your application.

HTH